# Control brightness on Acer laptop with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: laptop, brightness, acer

The brightness controls (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  / <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + ) on an [Acer 5733](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/support-product/3680?b=1) laptop were not working. The solution was to edit the `GRUB` like this:

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open the terminal.
2. Run this command: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.
3. Change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to close and then <kbd>Y</kbd> to save the change.
5. Run this command: `sudo update-grub`
6. Reboot.

Controls are working fine now.

Comment: Is there a Question associated with this Answer?